# How to redirect folders in Home

Tags: files

Fairly newby to EOS. I've done some spelunking around and the answers to this question are so old they no longer work.

I'm on Jolnir, so here goes:

[image]

I've got a separate hard drive with files that I share with a Windows boot. How do I point the various folders in Home to that drive?

thanks,

Answer (score 0):

The solution, after a bit of navel grazing, was to delete the folders in the /home folder and replace them with symbolic links to the appropriated folders in the mounted drive.